# Replace characters in ColdFusion string

Tags: coldfusion, passwords, coldfusion-9

I have a function on my website (ColdFusion) which sends a password reminder in an email. I'd like to replace all characters in the password string except the first and last - so reminder emails don't include the whole password...

So, instead of the email including 'Password123' it would include 'P*...*3'

As you have guessed I am not a developer. I can find the `<cfoutput>#password#</cfoutput>` in the email template. Is there a string handling function I can use for the above?

It's not a requirement that the function replaces the exact number of original characters. It can just be first and last, everything else replaced with '*...*'.

Comment: This doesn't solve your question, but it's obvious from the question that you are storing the password in plain text. This is always a bad idea. Passwords should be stored as a salted hash so that no one who is looking at the database can get a list of all your user's passwords. Read more about it here: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Secure_Password_Storage/

Comment: Excellent point @beloitdavisja. Really you should not even send any kind of password back to the user. And you won't be able to when you start storing the password as a hash. Instead you give them the ability to reset their password or send them a temp password that must be reset on initial login.

Comment: I'll reiterate, because I don't think this can be mentioned enough, a password should never be recoverable. If someone forgets their password, it should be reset.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Just use the function `left()` to get the first character and the function `right()` to get the last character.  I would not recommend replacing all of the other characters with a `.` or whatever.  You would be disclosing the actual number of characters in the password.  Instead I would just always put three `.` or `*` in between the first and last characters.

Here is some code that will do that for you.  Note that I also included an example of how to replace each of the other characters in between but I don't recommend doing that.

```
<cfscript>
password = 'Password123';
password_firstchar = left(password,1);
password_lastchar = right(password,1);

writeOutput(password_firstchar & '***' & password_lastchar);

writeOutput('<p>&nbsp;</p>');

writeOutput(password_firstchar);
writeOutput(repeatString('.',len(password)-2));
writeOutput(password_lastchar);
</cfscript>
```

Output from running that code is:

```
P***3

P.........3
```

And here is a gist of that code so you can run it and play with it - [TryCF gist example](https://www.trycf.com/gist/94d05f5f8cbddea7f83dee1b15757118/acf?theme=monokai)

NOTE: You indicated ColdFusion 9 as your platform. That version had limited `cfscript` syntax support.  I think what I have given you will still work on that version but if not let me know.  You could use the tag syntax instead.

[Here is an example that includes the tag syntax as well](https://www.trycf.com/gist/41df9f9bda7bc852b35f83aa44cdedad/acf?theme=monokai).

Comment: Which one is better, using Regex or using your solution?

Comment: I think for such a simple thing as this RegEx is not needed. But it would definitely work.  Feel free to post an answer with example if you want. There are numerous ways to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd not even recommend a solution here. Not to be unhelpful, but because the very premise of the question should be strongly discouraged. Miguel-F's answer will do the original request as asked, but it does not address the real problem here, which is the plain-text storage of a password.

You may be limited in what you can do with the password right now, but I'd seriously consider going back and fixing the way you work with passwords, instead of trying to obscure what you have in an email notification. It will be a bigger headache now, but it will save you tons of headaches in a breach. A password should never be recoverable.

Check out https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.

NOTE: To replace all but first and last character in a string, you can drop down into CF's Java implementation and use Java Regex (which is a bit better than CF's). I *think* this works in CF9, replaceAll() should be in the CF9 JDK. You'll have to try it.

```
<cfset mystring = "Password1234" >
<cfset masked = mystring.replaceAll("(?<=.).(?!$)", "*")>
<cfoutput>#masked#</cfoutput>
```

https://trycf.com/gist/c33d8a9b8e7edfedb935fc7ce6654cd7/acf?theme=monokai
https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: NOTE 2: Doing a replace like this significantly reduces the entropy of the password and will make it much easier to abuse. This will give the first and last characters and the length of their password.